# While doing a practice db migration in rails using irb, receiving error message "NameError:uninitialized constant ActiveRecord"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, irb

(see title)
here is the code, I'm using ms command prompt (irb) to do this, which may in itself be wrong.

> C:\Users\davo\Desktop\RailsProjects\sqlite>irb
>
> \<\lass CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
>
> irb(main):002:1> def up
>
> irb(main):003:2> create_table :products do |t|
>
> irb(main):004:3* t.string :name
>
> irb(main):005:3> t.text :description
>
> irb(main):006:3> t.timestamps
>
> irb(main):007:3> end
>
> irb(main):008:2> end
>
> irb(main):009:1> end
>
> NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
>
> ```
>    from (irb):1
>
>    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
> ```
>
> irb(main):010:0>

I know that it's not supposed to be \<\lass but that's not what I typed and I think that's not the issue but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `require 'active_record'`. I agree that you may run into other issues trying to migrate by hand.

Comment: What is the better way to do it? I'm a noob to rails. I'll look into it but I'd appreciate some Google-searchable keywords

Comment: Just do the migration, then reverse it with `db:rollback`. Take a look at the [Rails Migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back) for more info.

Comment: Everything works now that I've ironed out my problems with mysql. Everything works when mysql works in my experience.